# Firebase rules for multiple databses

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an Android app using Firebase Realtime Database.
My project contains 3 distinct databases:

1. Database 1: for common items;
2. Database 2: for feature A;
3. Database 3: for feature B;

In database 1, I'm able to create rules (working for this database) using its nodes to validate if specific user is able to read and write any data, for instance:

```
{
  "rules": 
  {
    "plants":
    {
      ".read": true, /*"auth !== null",*/
      ".write": "auth !== null && root.child('userRegistration/' + auth.uid).child('profileTypeInfo').val()=='0'"
    },
    "criteria":
    {
      ".read": "auth !== null",
      ".write": "auth !== null && root.child('userRegistration/' + auth.uid).child('profileTypeInfo').val()=='0'"
    },
    "guide":
    {
      ".read": "auth !== null",
      ".write": "auth !== null && root.child('userRegistration/' + auth.uid).child('profileTypeInfo').val()=='0'"
    },
    "userRegistration":
    {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    },
      "report" : 
      {
        ".read": "auth !== null && root.child('userRegistration/' + auth.uid).child('isActiveInfo').val()==true",
        ".write": "auth !== null && root.child('userRegistration/' + auth.uid).child('isActiveInfo').val()==true",
      }
  }
}
```

For this Database is OK, because I'm using the **root.child** of the current database. The issue is related to database A and B, because I'd like to use something like this:

```
database1.child('userRegistration/' + auth.uid).child('profileTypeInfo').val()=='0'"
```

instead of using

```
root.child('userRegistration/' + auth.uid).child('profileTypeInfo').val()=='0'"
```

In other words, I need using the child data from the **database 1** despite of using the **root** child, which not contains the child **userRegistration**

I do appreciate your help!

Comment: why did you cut your database in 3 ? I'm not seeing any way to have global rules in firebase right now

Comment: Hi @mcfly, in my scope I do need separate in multiple data base due to different versions. If I use just one (as previously) I would do lof of stuff  through java. I know how to do it via java but via Firebase rules are more reliable, I mean, I would spent to much effort do to the same in java

Comment: what about put your old version data into a sub collection and keep having only one databse ?

Comment: You're right! That would be a great possibility such as:
Root (being able to use the rules easily)
  Subcollection 1
  SubCollection 2
  SubCollection 3

Comment: Glad it helps :)